# ValueError: Shapes (None, 8) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Tags: python, keras, sequential

I'm building an ANN model for an audio classification project. I get an error upon calculating the accuracy of the model. The shape of X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test & the error message can be seen below in the code:

```
     X_train.shape
     (162, 1122)

     X_test.shape
     (31, 1122)

     y_train.shape
     (162, 10)

     y_test.shape
     (31, 8)      

     score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
     accuracy = 100*score[1]
     
     ValueError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-56-8528a33f6df3> in <module>
----> 1 score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
      2 accuracy = 100*score[1]
     ValueError: Shapes (None, 8) and (None, 10) are incompatible
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why do `y_train` and `y_test` not have the same output size? You can fix this issue by providing the correct size.

Comment: I have provided the correct size for y_train and y_test, but still, get the same value error.

Comment: They can't be the correct size, because one has samples of size 10 and the other samples of size 8. You need to use different data that matches your model.

Comment: What I meant was I rectified by matching the sample size of both y_train and y_test which are equal, yet I get the same error. I should have been more specific in my earlier comment, my bad.